# Check if value is false, true or null

Tags: javascript

I want to check if variable is false, true or null. If null or undefined assign array to the variable by default. In other languages this syntax would be just fine to use. In js however when value is false then it assign array to `myBool`

```js
const boolFromBody = false;
const myBool = boolFromBody || [true, false];
console.log(myBool)
```

I managed to do it with this syntax where I only check for null value

```js
const boolFromBody = null;
let otherBool = boolFromBody;
if (boolFromBody === null) {
  otherBool = [true, false]
}
console.log(otherBool);
```

Is there any better way to do it in js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nullish coalescing.

Checks if a variable is either null or undefined and assign it to a default value if it's the case. `0` or `false` are not considered as nullish and will be assigned to the value.

The nullish coalescing operator `??` acts very similar to the `||` operator, except that we don’t use “truthy” when evaluating the operator. Instead we use the definition of `nullish`, meaning “is the value strictly equal to `null` or `undefined`?”

```js
let a = null;

let b = a ?? "test";

console.log(b);
```

Example with `false`

```js
let a = false;

let b = a ?? "test";

console.log(b);
```

Comment: All right... I knew there must be some better way.. Thanks

Comment: @delmin note here it isnt supported by all browsers if you use it in the frontend, so you might want to use it in combination with babel

Comment: I've noticed that... It works in my project so everything is ok.. Thanks

Comment: "0 or false are not considered as falsy " -> you rather  mean "nullish" or "nully" here, instead of "falsy" right ?

Comment: @Pac0 well where is the concrete difference here

Comment: I think "nullish" instead of "falsy" sounds fine, as you wrote in first line. For me, `0`, `false` etc... are just "falsy", always, in javascript, because whenever they are coerced to boolean (`if (myVar) ` ) they are evaluated as false. With `??`, the value is not coerced to a boolean, it's coerced to only one of  `null` /`undefined` (what I think as "nullish") or  'anything else' (non-nullish)

Comment: @Pac0 thank you, the V8 developer documentation made me clear where the difference is

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative to the other answer that ensures backwards compatibility (it's supported even by IE6) because it doesn't make use of the nullish coalescing operator. It's more verbose but also more convenient and accessible if you aren't using babel.
Hope it helps!

```js
const boolFromBody = null;
let myBool = boolFromBody == (null || undefined) && [true, false];
console.log(myBool);
```

```js
const boolFromBody = undefined;
let myBool = boolFromBody == (null || undefined) && [true, false];
console.log(myBool);
```

```js
const boolFromBody = false;
let myBool = boolFromBody == (null || undefined) && [true, false];
console.log(myBool);
```